# Need Colemak-DHm mod keyboard layout in ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout, colemak

colemak keyboard layout is available in ubuntu, but its two variants mod DH and mod DHm are not available in ubuntu.
DHm mod overcomes its major problem of "H" key location.
It should be included in ubuntu.
It would be very helpful and much needed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, https://colemakmods.github.io/mod-dh/keyboards.html  already in shape.